# ¿Cómo usar Serial en una libreria de arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, print, printf, librería

Tengo una librería que he creado yo con c++ para usarla en Arduino(con su archivo .cpp y .h). La librería se compila bien y no da ningún error, pero cuando se ejecuta hay una cosa que no me funciona como yo quiero. En Arduino suelo usar Serial.print() y Serial.println() para ver lo que contienen variables ...etc. Pero he probado a importar Serial en la librería y me da un error. Hay alguna manera de usar el Serial para imprimir cosas dentro de una librería, o si saben alguna otra forma de saber lo que contienen variables, les estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Se hace de la misma forma que al usar Arduino, no hace falta importar nada extra, hay que importar Arduino.h eso si, pero después se puede usar Serial.print() y Serial.println() sin ningún problema.